# How does interact work with Haskell on a multiline string?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, interactive

I am trying to practise declarative programming using Haskell, I am running into some confusion with the interact function.

I can see from its type signature it operates on a whole string at once:

```
interact :: (String -> String) -> IO ()
```

What is the value of the string for a multiline input? I assume that it is a single string with a newline character inside of it?

For a Haskell program `Main.hs`

```
module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = interact( ... )
```

and a input file `input.txt`

```
5 6 7
3 6 10
```

If I run the compiled program like this:

```
$ Main < input.txt
```

Would the string that the interact is working with be:

```
5 6 7\n3 6 10
```

Comment: It will pass a string `"5 6 7\n3 6 10\n"` as parameter. So yes, you can use `lines` to convert it to a list of `String`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will pass `"5 6 7\n3 6 10\n"` as string. We can easily verify that by using `show` as function:

```
main = interact show
```

If we then call the progam with I/O redirection, we get:

```
./Main < data.dat
"5 6 7\n3 6 10\n"
```

You can make use of [**`lines :: String -> [String]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lines) to convert the `String` to a list of `String`s where each string is a line. If we change the program to:

```
main = interact (show . lines)
```

we see:

```
./Main < data.dat
["5 6 7","3 6 10"]
```

So by using `lines` in this case, we retrieve a list of two elements `"5 6 7"`, and `"3 6 9"`.